# ws.onmessage not called even though server is sending data

Tags: websocket

I'm using `sockjs-0.3.4`.
Before change page structure, it worked normally.
However after changing some stuff. abrubtly `ws.onmessage` function is beginning not to called.

I checked the connection with server by looking into `devtools`.
It looks like getting data from the server.
Please help me to know what's the point to check out.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0KXf.png)

```js
var statusWatcher = {
  curPage:"",
  ws: null,
  wsBaseUrl :null,
  uid: null,
  init : function(url ){
   if(statusWatcher.ws != null) return;
   console.log(statusWatcher.ws);
   console.log("wsBaseUrl:"+url)
   statusWatcher.wsBaseUrl = url;
   var browserSupport = ("WebSocket" in window)? true: false;
   if(browserSupport){
    statusWatcher.start();    
   }else{
    console.log("WebSocket is Not supported by your Web Browser!");
   }    
   //log.eventHandler(1);
  },
  start : function(){
   baseWsURL = statusWatcher.wsBaseUrl+"/statusCheck?&uid="+statusWatcher.uid;
   console.log("web socket baseurl:"+baseWsURL);
   try{
    statusWatcher.ws = new WebSocket(baseWsURL);
   } catch (e){
    console.log(e);
   }
   
   statusWatcher.ws.onopen = function() {
    console.log("web socket Opened! ");
   };


   statusWatcher.ws.onclose = function() {
    console.log("web syslog socket Closed! ");
   };

   statusWatcher.ws = function(err) {
    console.log("web syslog socket Error: " + err);
   };
   statusWatcher.ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    console.log("get message...");
    //console.log("page:"+curPage);
    var data = evt.data;
    console.log(data);
    var msg;
    if(curPage =="main") return;
    var e = JSON.parse(data);
    
    
     if(e.status =="COMPLETE"){
      $("#" + e.groupId).text("complete");
      $("#" + e.groupId).removeClass('run error');
      $("#" + e.groupId).addClass('complete');
      statusWatcher.updateScoreState(e.groupId, "COMPLETE", e.topRplRate,e.topKwdRate);
     }else if(e.status == "ERROR"){      
      $("#" + e.groupId).text("error");
      $("#" + e.groupId).removeClass('run complete');
      $("#" + e.groupId).addClass('error');
      statusWatcher.updateScoreState(e.groupId, "ERROR");
     }else{
      $("#" + e.groupId).html("running("+e.progress+"/"+e.total+")");
      $("#" + e.groupId).removeClass('error complete');
      $("#" + e.groupId).addClass('run');
      statusWatcher.updateScoreState(e.groupId, "RUNNING");
     }
    
   };
 
   
  },
      }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script src="<c:url value="js/fileuploadMain/statusWatcher.js"/>"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <!--header-->
    <c:import url="/WEB-INF/jsp/fileupload/header.jsp" /> 
    
    <!--contents--> 
    <div class="contents">
     <div class="container" id="container">
     </div>
    </div>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var nice = $("html").niceScroll();  // The document page (body)

            $(".select-items").niceScroll({
                zindex: "auto",boxzoom:false
            });
            
         $("#container").load("group.do");
         calaendar.init();
  
         
         var wsBaseUrl = "ws://"+document.location.host+"<c:out value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>";
         
         statusWatcher.init(wsBaseUrl);
        });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
statusWatcher.ws = function(err) {
            console.log("web syslog socket Error: " + err);
        };
```

I changed upper source code to the next..  Maybe I remove the function name mistakenly..

```
statusWatcher.ws.onerror = function(err) {
            console.log("web syslog socket Error: " + err);
        };
```